# How to arrange objects on curve in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I have created circle & tried placing object on it -

[image]

```
extension UIView {
    
    func createObjectsAroundCircle() {
        
        let center = CGPoint(x: -30, y: (bounds.height/2) - 100) //CGPointMake(bounds.width/2 ,bounds.width/2)
        let radius : CGFloat = (bounds.height/2) - 100
        let count = 6
        
        var angle = CGFloat(2 * Double.pi)
        let step = CGFloat( Double.pi) / CGFloat(count)
        print("angle, step", angle,step)
        
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)
        
//        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2))

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
        
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        
        // set objects around circle
        //            for var index = 0; index < count ; index++ {
        for index in 0..<count {
            let x = cos(angle) * radius + center.x
            let y = sin(angle) * radius + center.y
            
            
            print("x position, y position", x,y)
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = "\(index)"
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.frame.size.width = 40
            label.frame.size.height = 40
            label.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 20)
            label.textColor = UIColor.black
            label.backgroundColor = .red
            label.layer.cornerRadius = label.frame.size.height / 2
            label.layer.masksToBounds = true
            // label.sizeToFit()
            label.frame.origin.x = x - label.frame.midX
            label.frame.origin.y = y - label.frame.midY
            
            self.addSubview(label)
            angle += step
        }
    }
}
```

What i am looking for is -

[image]

Missing some Angle part on it. Or any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: Comment the line `let center = CGPoint(x: -30, y: (bounds.height/2) - 100)`, it should take the center of the view. Make your view a square (it's easier to debug), and run it again. You'll see your issue, the starting angle when you place your points is wrong. Debug from there your angles.